# How to empty a NSArrayController in swift

Tags: swift, nsarraycontroller

I suppose the answer is quite easy, but i did not manage to find an answer:

I am using a nscollectionview whos content is managed via an nsarraycontroller. adding objects works as intended but i do not find any method to remove all objects. there are several remove methods but something like .clear, .empty or .removeAll is not available.

Help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want like so :

```
let range : NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, yourArrayController.arrangedObjects.count)
let indexSet : NSIndexSet = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: range)

yourArrayController.removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes(indexSet)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

`[myArrayController setContent:nil];`

or Swift

`myArrayController.content = nil`

to purge.

So typically if resetting an array controller programmatically

```
-(void)setTargetObjects:(NSArray *)objects {

    [self.arrayController setContent:nil];

    [self.arrayController addObjects:objects];

}
```

or Swift

```
func setTargetObjects(objects:[AnyObject]) {

    self.arrayController.content = nil
    self.arrayController.addObjects(objects)

}
```

Comment: seems to be objective-c ;-) There is no setContent available to an NSArrayController...

Comment: oops - didn't notice swift tag  - see edit. setContent/content is on `NSObjectController` the parent